# what doesn't B take 8 as input? c++

Tags: c++, input, output

In the fhe following code, the input is `9/ 8`, so why doesn't `B` take `8` as input?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A, B;
    cin >> A >> B;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, What happens to the `/` in `9/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator>>` stops reading when it encounters a character that does not fit in the data type being read into.

In this case, your first call to `operator>>` is reading into `int A`, so it reads the `'9'` character and then stops reading when it encounters the non-digit `'/'` character.  The `'/'` character stays in the input stream.

Then your second call to `operator>>` tries to read into `int B`, but it reads the `'/'` character instead of the `'8'` character, so the read fails since `'/'` is not a digit.

You need to ignore the `'/'` in order to read the `'8'` character, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A, B;
    char ignore;
    cin >> A >> ignore >> B;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A, B;
    cin >> A >> ws;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> B;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> input is 9/ 8 why doesn't B take 8 as input?

Because "/ 8" is not a number.